# New conjecture? $(\varphi(n))! = -1 \pmod n \iff n$ is prime (nearly the same as Wilson's)

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, totient-function, conjectures, primality-test

$$
(n-1)! = -1 \pmod n \text{ iff } n \text{ is prime}, \text{ is Wilson's theorem,}
$$

But coincidentally for now the expression passed to factorial is $n - 1$ which is (iff $n$ is prime) equal to $\varphi(n)$.  So, I was thinking, don't we have this related conjecture:

$$
\varphi(n)! = -1 \pmod n \text{ iff } n \text{ is prime}
$$

Because the following example verification code seems to indicate as such:

```
from sympy import *

N = 10000

for n in range(2, N):    
    r = factorial(totient(n)) % n
    
    if isprime(n):
        assert (r + 1) % n == 0        
    else:
        assert (r + 1) % n != 0
        
    print(n, r)
```

Which prints:

```
2 1
3 2
4 2
5 4
6 2
7 6
8 0
9 0
10 4
11 10
12 0
13 12
14 6
15 0
16 0
17 16
18 0
19 18
20 0
21 0
22 10
23 22
24 0
25 0
26 12
27 0
28 0
29 28
30 0
31 30
32 0
33 0
34 16
35 0
36 0
37 36
38 18
39 0
40 0
41 40
42 0
43 42
44 0
45 0
46 22
47 46
48 0
49 0
50 0
51 0
52 0
53 52
54 0
55 0
56 0
57 0
58 28
59 58
60 0
61 60
62 30
63 0
64 0
65 0
66 0
67 66
68 0
69 0
70 0
71 70
72 0
73 72
74 36
75 0
76 0
77 0
78 0
79 78
80 0
81 0
82 40
83 82
84 0
85 0
86 42
87 0
88 0
89 88
90 0
91 0
92 0
93 0
94 46
95 0
96 0
97 96
98 0
99 0
100 0
101 100
102 0
103 102
104 0
105 0
106 52
107 106
108 0
109 108
110 0
111 0
112 0
113 112
114 0
115 0
116 0
117 0
118 58
119 0
120 0
121 0
122 60
123 0
124 0
125 0
126 0
127 126
128 0
129 0
130 0
131 130
132 0
133 0
134 66
135 0
136 0
137 136
138 0
139 138
140 0
141 0
142 70
143 0
144 0
145 0
146 72
147 0
148 0
149 148
150 0
151 150
152 0
153 0
154 0
155 0
156 0
157 156
158 78
159 0
160 0
161 0
162 0
163 162
164 0
165 0
166 82
167 166
168 0
169 0
170 0
171 0
172 0
173 172
174 0
175 0
176 0
177 0
178 88
179 178
180 0
181 180
182 0
183 0
184 0
185 0
186 0
187 0
188 0
189 0
190 0
191 190
192 0
193 192
194 96
195 0
196 0
197 196
198 0
199 198
200 0
201 0
202 100
203 0
204 0
205 0
206 102
207 0
208 0
209 0
210 0
211 210
212 0
213 0
214 106
215 0
216 0
217 0
218 108
219 0
220 0
221 0
222 0
223 222
224 0
225 0
226 112
227 226
228 0
229 228
230 0
231 0
232 0
233 232
234 0
235 0
236 0
237 0
238 0
239 238
240 0
241 240
242 0
243 0
244 0
245 0
246 0
247 0
248 0
249 0
250 0
251 250
252 0
253 0
254 126
255 0
256 0
257 256
258 0
259 0
260 0
261 0
262 130
263 262
264 0
265 0
266 0
267 0
268 0
269 268
270 0
271 270
272 0
273 0
274 136
275 0
276 0
277 276
278 138
279 0
280 0
281 280
282 0
283 282
284 0
285 0
286 0
287 0
288 0
289 0
290 0
291 0
292 0
293 292
294 0
295 0
296 0
297 0
298 148
299 0
300 0
301 0
302 150
303 0
304 0
305 0
306 0
307 306
308 0
309 0
310 0
311 310
312 0
313 312
314 156
315 0
316 0
317 316
318 0
319 0
320 0
321 0
322 0
323 0
324 0
325 0
326 162
327 0
328 0
329 0
330 0
331 330
332 0
333 0
334 166
335 0
336 0
337 336
338 0
339 0
340 0
341 0
342 0
343 0
344 0
345 0
346 172
347 346
348 0
349 348
350 0
351 0
352 0
353 352
354 0
355 0
356 0
357 0
358 178
359 358
360 0
361 0
362 180
363 0
364 0
365 0
366 0
367 366
368 0
369 0
370 0
371 0
372 0
373 372
374 0
375 0
376 0
377 0
378 0
379 378
380 0
381 0
382 190
383 382
384 0
385 0
386 192
387 0
388 0
389 388
390 0
391 0
392 0
393 0
394 196
395 0
396 0
397 396
398 198
399 0
400 0
401 400
402 0
403 0
404 0
405 0
406 0
407 0
408 0
409 408
410 0
411 0
412 0
413 0
414 0
415 0
416 0
417 0
418 0
419 418
420 0
421 420
422 210
423 0
424 0
425 0
426 0
427 0
428 0
429 0
430 0
431 430
432 0
433 432
434 0
435 0
436 0
437 0
438 0
439 438
440 0
441 0
442 0
443 442
444 0
445 0
446 222
447 0
448 0
449 448
450 0
451 0
452 0
453 0
454 226
455 0
456 0
457 456
458 228
459 0
460 0
461 460
462 0
463 462
464 0
465 0
466 232
467 466
468 0
469 0
470 0
471 0
472 0
473 0
474 0
475 0
476 0
477 0
478 238
479 478
480 0
481 0
482 240
483 0
484 0
485 0
486 0
487 486
488 0
489 0
490 0
491 490
492 0
493 0
494 0
495 0
496 0
497 0
498 0
499 498
500 0
501 0
502 250
503 502
504 0
505 0
506 0
507 0
508 0
509 508
510 0
511 0
512 0
513 0
514 256
515 0
516 0
517 0
518 0
519 0
520 0
521 520
522 0
523 522
524 0
525 0
526 262
527 0
528 0
529 0
530 0
531 0
532 0
533 0
534 0
535 0
536 0
537 0
538 268
539 0
540 0
541 540
542 270
543 0
544 0
545 0
546 0
547 546
548 0
549 0
550 0
551 0
552 0
553 0
554 276
555 0
556 0
557 556
558 0
559 0
560 0
561 0
562 280
563 562
564 0
565 0
566 282
567 0
568 0
569 568
570 0
571 570
572 0
573 0
574 0
575 0
576 0
577 576
578 0
579 0
580 0
581 0
582 0
583 0
584 0
585 0
586 292
587 586
588 0
589 0
590 0
591 0
592 0
593 592
594 0
595 0
596 0
597 0
598 0
599 598
600 0
601 600
602 0
603 0
604 0
605 0
606 0
607 606
608 0
609 0
610 0
611 0
612 0
613 612
614 306
615 0
616 0
617 616
618 0
619 618
620 0
621 0
622 310
623 0
624 0
625 0
626 312
627 0
628 0
629 0
630 0
631 630
632 0
633 0
634 316
635 0
636 0
637 0
638 0
639 0
640 0
641 640
642 0
643 642
644 0
645 0
646 0
647 646
648 0
649 0
650 0
651 0
652 0
653 652
654 0
655 0
656 0
657 0
658 0
659 658
660 0
661 660
662 330
663 0
664 0
665 0
666 0
667 0
668 0
669 0
670 0
671 0
672 0
673 672
674 336
675 0
676 0
677 676
678 0
679 0
680 0
681 0
682 0
683 682
684 0
685 0
686 0
687 0
688 0
689 0
690 0
691 690
692 0
693 0
694 346
695 0
696 0
697 0
698 348
699 0
700 0
701 700
702 0
703 0
704 0
705 0
706 352
707 0
708 0
709 708
710 0
711 0
712 0
713 0
714 0
715 0
716 0
717 0
718 358
719 718
720 0
721 0
722 0
723 0
724 0
725 0
726 0
727 726
728 0
729 0
730 0
731 0
732 0
733 732
734 366
735 0
736 0
737 0
738 0
739 738
740 0
741 0
742 0
743 742
744 0
745 0
746 372
747 0
748 0
749 0
750 0
751 750
752 0
753 0
754 0
755 0
756 0
757 756
758 378
759 0
760 0
761 760
762 0
763 0
764 0
765 0
766 382
767 0
768 0
769 768
770 0
771 0
772 0
773 772
774 0
775 0
776 0
777 0
778 388
779 0
780 0
781 0
782 0
783 0
784 0
785 0
786 0
787 786
788 0
789 0
790 0
791 0
792 0
793 0
794 396
795 0
796 0
797 796
798 0
799 0
800 0
801 0
802 400
803 0
804 0
805 0
806 0
807 0
808 0
809 808
810 0
811 810
812 0
813 0
814 0
815 0
816 0
817 0
818 408
819 0
820 0
821 820
822 0
823 822
824 0
825 0
826 0
827 826
828 0
829 828
830 0
831 0
832 0
833 0
834 0
835 0
836 0
837 0
838 418
839 838
840 0
841 0
842 420
843 0
844 0
845 0
846 0
847 0
848 0
849 0
850 0
851 0
852 0
853 852
854 0
855 0
856 0
857 856
858 0
859 858
860 0
861 0
862 430
863 862
864 0
865 0
866 432
867 0
868 0
869 0
870 0
871 0
872 0
873 0
874 0
875 0
876 0
877 876
878 438
879 0
880 0
881 880
882 0
883 882
884 0
885 0
886 442
887 886
888 0
889 0
890 0
891 0
892 0
893 0
894 0
895 0
896 0
897 0
898 448
899 0
900 0
901 0
902 0
903 0
904 0
905 0
906 0
907 906
908 0
909 0
910 0
911 910
912 0
913 0
914 456
915 0
916 0
917 0
918 0
919 918
920 0
921 0
922 460
923 0
924 0
925 0
926 462
927 0
928 0
929 928
930 0
931 0
932 0
933 0
934 466
935 0
936 0
937 936
938 0
939 0
940 0
941 940
942 0
943 0
944 0
945 0
946 0
947 946
948 0
949 0
950 0
951 0
952 0
953 952
954 0
955 0
956 0
957 0
958 478
959 0
960 0
961 0
962 0
963 0
964 0
965 0
966 0
967 966
968 0
969 0
970 0
971 970
972 0
973 0
974 486
975 0
976 0
977 976
978 0
979 0
980 0
981 0
982 490
983 982
984 0
985 0
986 0
987 0
988 0
989 0
990 0
991 990
992 0
993 0
994 0
995 0
996 0
997 996
998 498
999 0
1000 0
1001 0
1002 0
1003 0
1004 0
1005 0
1006 502
1007 0
1008 0
1009 1008
1010 0
1011 0
1012 0
1013 1012
1014 0
1015 0
1016 0
1017 0
1018 508
1019 1018
1020 0
1021 1020
1022 0
1023 0
1024 0
1025 0
1026 0
1027 0
1028 0
1029 0
1030 0
1031 1030
1032 0
1033 1032
1034 0
1035 0
1036 0
1037 0
1038 0
1039 1038
1040 0
1041 0
1042 520
1043 0
1044 0
1045 0
1046 522
1047 0
1048 0
1049 1048
1050 0
1051 1050
1052 0
1053 0
1054 0
1055 0
1056 0
1057 0
1058 0
1059 0
1060 0
1061 1060
1062 0
1063 1062
1064 0
1065 0
1066 0
1067 0
1068 0
1069 1068
1070 0
1071 0
1072 0
1073 0
1074 0
1075 0
1076 0
1077 0
1078 0
1079 0
1080 0
1081 0
1082 540
1083 0
1084 0
1085 0
1086 0
1087 1086
1088 0
1089 0
1090 0
1091 1090
1092 0
1093 1092
1094 546
1095 0
1096 0
1097 1096
1098 0
1099 0
1100 0
1101 0
1102 0
1103 1102
1104 0
1105 0
1106 0
1107 0
1108 0
1109 1108
1110 0
1111 0
1112 0
1113 0
1114 556
1115 0
1116 0
1117 1116
1118 0
1119 0
1120 0
1121 0
1122 0
1123 1122
1124 0
1125 0
1126 562
1127 0
1128 0
1129 1128
1130 0
1131 0
1132 0
1133 0
1134 0
1135 0
1136 0
1137 0
1138 568
1139 0
1140 0
1141 0
1142 570
1143 0
1144 0
1145 0
1146 0
1147 0
1148 0
1149 0
1150 0
1151 1150
1152 0
1153 1152
1154 576
1155 0
1156 0
1157 0
1158 0
1159 0
1160 0
1161 0
1162 0
1163 1162
1164 0
1165 0
1166 0
1167 0
1168 0
1169 0
1170 0
1171 1170
1172 0
1173 0
1174 586
1175 0
1176 0
1177 0
1178 0
1179 0
1180 0
1181 1180
1182 0
1183 0
1184 0
1185 0
1186 592
1187 1186
1188 0
1189 0
1190 0
1191 0
1192 0
1193 1192
1194 0
1195 0
1196 0
1197 0
1198 598
1199 0
1200 0
1201 1200
1202 600
1203 0
1204 0
1205 0
1206 0
1207 0
1208 0
1209 0
1210 0
1211 0
1212 0
1213 1212
1214 606
1215 0
1216 0
1217 1216
1218 0
1219 0
1220 0
1221 0
1222 0
1223 1222
```

In other words, it does not halt at an assertion checkpoint!  And the conjecture appears true.

**Questions.**

How can we prove this?  Do you already have a proof in mind?  Is this a new conjecture?

Comment: Thanks for the upvote.  I am OEIS'ing the sequence now because that will tell us a lot.  OEIS recovered nothing but that doesn't mean it's not there disguised with maybe -1 entries (all my sequence output is standard residue modulo $n$ which can't be $-1$).

Comment: I also used Approach zero to search for simply $\varphi(n)!$ and nothing came up there, so...

Comment: Needless to say this is not of any use in showing primality as there is no known efficient method to compute $\varphi(n)$ without already knowing prime factorization of $n$ (and if there was such a method then it would be much simpler to check $\varphi(n)=n-1$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple argument:

1. If $n$ is prime, then obviously $$(\varphi(n))! \equiv (n-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod n.$$
2. Suppose $$(\varphi(n))! \equiv -1 \pmod n$$If any number $k$ in the first $\varphi(n)$ numbers is not coprime to $n$, then this can never be $-1$ modulo $n$. So, we get that $n$ is coprime with all numbers from $1$ to $\varphi(n)$. This means $n$ is not coprime with any number after $\varphi(n)$ (by definition of $\varphi$).
   Since $(n,n-1) = 1$, $\varphi(n) = n-1$, and the rest follows.

---

Consider $k \in \{1,2,3 \ldots \varphi(n)\}$. If $\gcd(k,n)>1$, then $(\varphi(n))!$ can't be $-1$ modulo $n$ as that would imply $k$ divides $(\varphi(n))! = xn - 1$ for some $x \in \Bbb Z$, but this is not possible. Since there are exactly $\varphi(n)$ integers in the set $\{1,2,3\ldots , n\}$ coprime to $n$, we know that these integers are exactly the elements of $\{1,2,3 \ldots \varphi(n)\}$. Done.

Answer (score 3):

The claim is true.

If $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$ is a prime factorization of $n$ with $p_1\lt p_2\lt\cdots\lt p_r$ primes and $a_i\geq 1$ for all $i$, then
$$\varphi(n) = (p_1-1)p_1^{a_1-1}\cdots (p_r-1)p_r^{a_r-1}.$$
If $n$ is not squarefree, or is even and not $2$, then $\gcd(n,\varphi(n))\gt 1$. In particular, $\varphi(n)!$ cannot be a unit modulo $n$.

If $n$ is squarefree and $r\gt 1$, then $p_1\leq p_2-1\leq \varphi(n)$, so $\gcd(n,\varphi(n)!)\gt 1$. Again, $\varphi(n)!$ cannot be a unit modulo $n$.

The only remaining case is $n$ prime, in which case the congruence is Wilson's Theorem.